# Is it possible to rewrite iphdr's saddr attribute?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, netfilter

I'm writing a kernel module that blocks access to particular website by using net filter and it's working great. I have registered hook for NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING and can check if the request is http request and the ip address request is made to. From here, I would like to extend the functionality of my module in a way that request made to particular website is redirected to another website. I'm thinking about rewriting saddr attribute of iphdr struct. Is it feasible approach? I tried to rewrite saddr attribute but the request does not get redirected. Wget just stops responding.

This is snippet of my code -

```
// This code is inside hook function
__be32 test = ntohl(0xCC4FC5C8);
ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);    
ip_header->saddr = test;
return NF_ACCEPT;
```

Kernel Version - 3.19
UBuntu

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to redirect the tcp request by using netfilter. If I remember correctly, only packets that contains payload will go through the netfilter framework, but packets such as sync in the three-way handshake will be handled and responded by interface card. The reason for doing that is probably performance.

Therefore what may happen to your program is that the packets with http requests are actually redirected to `test`, but not for syns, which means there is not even a tcp connection set up between your client and `test`. I would suggest use wireshark to check whether all packets are redirected to `test`.

Maybe you can try a proxy server, instead of doing all in the kernel module.

Please definitely correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I haven't tested with wireshark but it is very likely that what you said is true. I tested with printk to see what's going on and found out that the client keeps making request to the same IP address and does not acknowledge any changes I have made. I'm thinking about using different approach which is hooking into connect system call.

Comment: I just realized that you forgot to recalculate the checksum of the ip headers. Network card will drop packets with invalid checksum.

Comment: Do you know how to recalculate checksum?

Comment: @user30646 there's a function called ip_send_check for recalculating ip header checksum, but I'm not sure it exists in kernel module. However, the checksum algorithm is relatively easy to write and you can find it easier via google.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually working on something similar to this, but in userspace.

What you will likely need to do is sniff the packets until you get the initial `GET` request with the `Host` header. If it matches a host you want to redirect to somewhere else, fake a response from the web server with a `302 Redirect` response. You may still need to keep track of the connection itself to handle FINs, etc.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is sound and you're almost there.

First and as suggested by @ruofan, you need to make sure to update the ip header checksum of redirected packets. You may also have to update their TCP header checksum depending on what you're doing.

Also, if you want to redirect traffic meant for one website to another, you should be editing the `daddr` field of ip headers, not their `saddr` field. Note that you may later need to alter the `saddr` ip header field of the response packets for your application to handle them properly.

Last but not least, remember that you should modify destination-related fields from hooks registered to `NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING` and source-related fields from hooks registered to `NF_INET_POST_ROUTING`.

Good luck!